# Today date & next 2 days without showing the weekends - display in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

May I request to check the code on how can I disable/not show the weekends on the select dropdown?

```
<select style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000;" name="address3" id="date-range" data-field-type="Text">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select date</option>
</select>

<script>
  var dateRange = document.getElementById('date-range'),
  monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

  for(var day = 2; day < 120; day++) {
    var date = new Date();
    
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);

    dateRange.options[dateRange.options.length] = new Option(
        [date.getDate(), monthNames[date.getMonth()], date.getFullYear()].join(' '), date.toISOString()
      );
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Is your code working for days greater than 31 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var dateRange = document.getElementById('date-range'),
    monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

for(var day = 3; day < 120; day++) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + day);
   if(!(date.getDay()==6|| date.getDay()==0))
        dateRange.options[dateRange.options.length] = new Option([date.getDate(), monthNames[date.getMonth()], date.getFullYear()].join(' '), date.toISOString());
}
```

```html
 <select style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000;" name="address3" id="date-range" data-field-type="Text">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Select date</option>
 </select>
```